# What exactly happens to the Traveler at the end of Destiny 2's Campaign? *spoilers*

Tags: destiny-2

At the end of the Boss fight with Dominus Ghaul, he becomes a giant form of liquid gold light; he then turns to the Traveler as blue lines start to form and crack under the shield the Red Legion used to trap it, and that same shield is broken by the traveler.

Ghaul then says "You do see me..." as the traveler explodes and a wave of its blue light shoots out into the galaxy with itself as the center. This is the same blue energy that can be found on Io.

What is the traveler doing here? It's never really explained in the story, but it's visible from the tower for the rest of the game.

Comment: Usually one would use the spoiler tag here to hide text, but that would essentially hide more than half of the question. Not sure what to do...

Comment: @Fabian is the spoiler notice in the title sufficient? Also, thanks for the advice.

Comment: It's the best you can do in my opinion. The spoiler tag is more a convenience for others than really necessary.

Comment: Our rule of thumb for spoilers is: Does the question make sense without the spoiled text? If so, then you're fine. If the question doesn't, then you should probably unspoiled it until it does.

Comment: From what I understand the Traveler has re-awoken as it has been dormant above the Earth for a very long time. Why it chose this moment and what Ghaul says is up for debate.

Answer (score 1):

From the [wiki](https://www.destinypedia.com/Traveler)

> Nonetheless it was captured at the start of Destiny 2 by the Cabal Red Legion and taken from humanity, weakening Guardians severely, only to reawaken after countless millennia to smite its leader Dominus Ghaul and putting an end to the Red War.

Basically, Ghaul caused the Traveler to wake up after being put under the amount of stress that "draining the Light" caused. Ghaul mistook this for "seeing him", but it's more than likely still unaware of individuals the same way a human is unaware of individual ants.

At this point however, nothing more is known about the Traveler, other than it is now "awake", as it does nothing else after this point*.

---

<sup>* I have not played the DLC, so I don't know if this uncovers anything more about the Traveler</sup>

Comment: The DLC addresses pretty much nothing, especially nothing to do with the Traveler.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the traveler doing here? It's never really explained in the
>   story, but it's visible from the tower for the rest of the game.

In Destiny 1 it was very vaguely explained that as the Traveler came to our solar system and ushered in a new era of enlightenment by terra-forming planets, extending human life to 200 years, etc. that the ever illusive "Darkness" came and attacked humanity.

It was said to have it us hard enough to push us all the way back to a single city on Earth (the one the Tower resides in). In the last dire moments of this fight for survival the Traveler used the "last" of it's power to create the Ghost and thus making the Guardians.

Because the Traveler used the apparent last bits of its energy to do so it has floated dormant over the city. This is why the Traveler has been just chilling during the games.

Hopefully that answers part of your question.